# jmeter reports errors loading socket component

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

[image]

I'd want to use websocket-samplers by Peter Doornbosch and any of his components in the list if chosen will reports that error. I use jmeter-plugin to install his. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question cannot be comprehensively answered as you need to provide:

1. Contents of "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Contents of "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation
3. Contents of other folders in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) if it was amended somehow
4. Contents of [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) preferably with [debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging)

Most probably it's connected somehow with JMeter version, current release of WebSocket Samplers [relies on JMeter 3.1](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/e7a694f4f98aa83541a80fe1e64c0761b00db5ce/build.gradle#lines-13:22) so you need to use at least this version for your testing (however it's [recommended to use the latest JMeter when and where possible](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version))

Comment: I'm using jmeter 5.5 , i download it and just run  it then install the plugin but the plugin fails to work